# ATmega328P-AU VCC and capacitors & software uploads

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, atmega328p

I've designed a circuit to utilise the ATmega328P-AU on a PCBA. I'm having trouble uploading software to the chip, and wanted to check whether you think that it's okay to have both VCC connected to ground via the same capacitor (see picture of schematic). I'm wondering if this is causing problems.

Edit:
Reset is set to +5V by default.
AVCC is connected to the same power supply using a seperate capacitor between vcc and ground. (I am not using anything analog in this circuit).
The chip is bootloaded to use the 8MHz internal clock. (bootloading was manual and successful as far as I can tell).

Edit:
I'm utilising the Arduino IDE and the MiniCore library to bootload the chip and upload the software. Bootloading is successful, but during programming I get the error:

Edit:
The example breadboard for programming which I designed into the PCB (the external crystal was not included).
[image]

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xdd.
```

My schematic for the PCB based of the breadboard test.
[image]

Comment: That's probably ok.  Click the edit link below your question and please answer: What is Avcc connected to?  What is the state of RESET?  Where is the crystal/oscillator (and if none because of config bits, how are those bits to be programmed initially?)  Most micros include config bits for a variety of internal and external oscillators - are you sure yours is set (or defaults) correctly?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've got it correctly bootloaded to use the 8MHz internal oscillator. I've edited the picture to include the other side which has AVCC

Comment: I've also edited the post to include the answers to your other questions.

Comment: What trouble you are having and how are you trying to upload firmware?

Comment: I'm using Arduino to programme the chip. I get an AVR dude error: 
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xdd.
I'm using the Minicore library to bootload and upload to the chip.

Comment: What is "ProgReset" and why is there a series cap to it? That looks wrong. Instead the reset pin should have a decoupling cap to ground as per manufacturer recommendations.

Comment: ProgReset is the Reset pin (connected to the DTR pin of the FTDI connector I'm using to program the chip). According to the breadboard example (see edited post) which I tested and validated with a DIP package ATMEGA328, the capacitor is required. As far as I can tell this is to: turn the reset signal into a momentary pulse low, to reset the MCU and make the bootloader run.

Comment: The reset is wrong if resistor is on wrong side. The breadboard layout is extremely poor, I hope you are not using it as example. It even has ground disconnected, it won't work. If the bootloader requires a crystal then it does not work without it. If you use an internal oscillator it may not be accurate enough for UART. Please try to debug if you need a crystal or if the internal oscillator is inaccurate or just runs at wrong frequency.

Comment: I had success in uploading software using arduino by reducing the bootloaded clock speed to 2MHz from 8. And also the RX and TX pins had to be reversed. Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capacitors on VCC and GND are fine. The RX and TX pins needed to be reversed (as TX > RX, and RX > TX), and the bootloaded oscillator speed lowered to 2MHz to provide consistent uploads.